# Windows Embedded Compact 7 Applicationwide Errorhandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I want to implement an applicationwide `Errorhandler` under `Windows Embedded Compact 7`. It shall catch all exceptions that haven't been caught on their way up the call stack.

It is a `Winforms Compact Framework 3.5,  C#` application. The application is multithreaded. 
Any hint, or also a link to usefull informations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) event. Main aspect of the code from the link.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);

//event handler
static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args) 
{
   Exception e = (Exception) args.ExceptionObject;
   Console.WriteLine("MyHandler caught : " + e.Message);
}
```

It seems the CF does not have an equivalent of the [ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). However, according to [this post](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/appdomainunhandledexception-part-1.aspx), it doesn't need it:

> With NETCF 2.0, we still don't have Application.ThreadException but,
>   unlike the desktop scenario, we don't need it since the NETCF 2.0
>   AppDomain.UnhandledException catches *all* unhandled exceptions.

I assume nothing has changed on that front from 2.0 to 3.5.